# Building a regex to capture INT., EXT., INT./EXT., etc

Tags: php, regex

I'm working through a bunch of text in which I'm looking for the following strings:

- INT.
- EXT.
- INT./EXT.
- EXT./INT.

The text under analysis is, for instance,

```
17   INT.   BLOOM HOUSE - NIGHT                                  17
27   INT./EXT.   BLOOM HOUSE - (PRESENT) DAY                      27
```

Calls in php to, for instance, 
`preg_match("/^\w.*(INT\.\/EXT\.|EXT\.\/INT\.|EXT\.|INT\.)(.*)$/", $a_line, $matches);`

and variants of that don't quite handle the greediness right (or so I think, anyway), and something gets left out, usually `INT./EXT.` or `EXT./INT.` items.  Any advice?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True, you need to use lazy dot matching with `\w.*?`, but you can also optimize the pattern to shorten the alternation group like this:

```
/^\w.*?(INT\.(?:\/EXT\.)?|EXT\.(?:\/INT\.)?)(.*)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gS1z8F/1)

Also, if you are processing the text as a whole, you will need a `/m` multiline modifer.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `\w` - a word char
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible up to the first
- `(INT\.(?:\/EXT\.)?|EXT\.(?:\/INT\.)?)` - Group 1 capturing either:

  - `INT\.(?:\/EXT\.)?` - `INT.` followed with optional `/EXT.` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `EXT\.(?:\/INT\.)?` - `EXT.` followed with optional `/INT.` substring
- `(.*)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars up to the...
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: A new, followup question: Can this be modified so that the numbers at the beginnings of my test strings are optional?  I tried to modify it (honest!), but just can't get it to work...

Comment: Replace `^\w` with `^`.

Comment: Wow -- fast feedback!  But I just realized I screwed up my question because I *actually* need to capture the initial number if it's there. `^(\w*)?.*?(INT\.(?:\/EXT\.)...` works well if the number is there, but not if it's not: the INT/EXT stuff gets messed up. Any further thoughts?

Comment: If you mean you may have the initial number optional, use [`^(\d+)?.*?(INT\.(?:\/EXT\.)?|EXT\.(?:\/INT\.)?)(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/WCPzK2/1).

Comment: Great! Last version (I promise!!!): If the string looks like `17A INT./EXT...` -- that is, if the opening thing is not just a number but a combination of digits and alphas.  I tried changing `\d+` to `\w+`, but without luck...

Comment: Try requiring a digit first - `(\d\w*)?`

Comment: Excellent -- THANKS VERY MUCH for your help!